# String Formatting in java with max width and closing bracket at the end of word

Tags: java, string, format

I want to get the below format

```
abc 12 [hello-wo]       this is message1
abc 12 [hello-world]    this is message2
abc 10 [hello-wor]      this is message2
```

I tried using

```
String format1 = "%s %d [%s-%s] %s\n";
String format2 = "%s %d [%s-%-20s] %s\n";
    String a = String.format(format1,"abc","12",hello,"wo","this is message1");
    System.out.print(a);
```

I resulted like below by using two formats (format1 and format2)

> format1

```
abc 12 [hello-wda] this is message1
abc 12 [hello-world] this is message2
abc 10 [hello-wor] this is message2
```

> format2

```
abc 12 [hello-wo                  ] this is message1
abc 12 [hello-world               ] this is message2
abc 12 [hello-wor                 ] this is message1
```

What I want is to align the last part of the parameter in same vertical position and closing square brackets should be at the end of the 4th parameter without any spaces.

Comment: So basically, you want an output such as `[hello-         world]` ; with the world word next to the closing bracket despite the length of it ?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is transforming the argument. This is not what formatters generally do (unless with numbers and dates, i.e. pretty specific stuff).

There is no way you can do what you want, I think, but you can work around it by using pattern and converting your args manually, like this:

The pattern:

```
String PATTERN = "%s %d [%s-%-21s %s\n"; // notice that I've removed the closing bracket.
                                         // See below
```

Applying the arguments:

```
String arg = "world";
arg = arg.trim();
arg = arg.substring(0, Math.min(arg.length(), 20));
String.format(PATTERN, "abc", "12", "hello",
    /*Attention here: changing next argument by appending close bracket */
    arg + "]",
    "this is the message");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a trick how you can solve your problem :

```
public void formatString(String hello) {
    String format1 = "%s %s %s\n";
    String firstPart = String.format("%s %d [%s-%s]", "abc", 12, hello, "wo");
    String a = String.format(
            format1, firstPart, 
            String.format("%0" + Math.abs(30 - firstPart.length()) + "d", 0).replace("0", " "), 
            "this is message1");
    System.out.print(a);
}
```

Test case :

```
formatString("hello-wda");
formatString("hello-world");
formatString("hello-wor");
```

Outputs

```
abc 12 [hello-wda-wo]           this is message1
abc 12 [hello-world-wo]         this is message1
abc 12 [hello-wor-wo]           this is message1
```

---

The trick is to use two format, the first one to create the first part, we need this part to calculate the number of space needs to be equilibrium, the second format to combine the first part + the spaces between the first and second part + second part.

I used 30 as default value you can change it with your needs.